# Mathematical Induction to show positive real number other than 1

Tags: induction

By mathematical induction I need to show that $a$ is a positive real number other than $1$, then

$$\sum^n_{j=1}{a^j}=(a)\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}$$

For each natural number $n$.

We us ethe first principle of mathematical induction. For the base case that $1^3=1=(\frac{1*2}{2})^2$. We presume that the above is true for all positive real numbers other than 1. Then

$$\sum^{n+1}_{j=1}{a^j}=(a)\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$$

Could I show this and then somehow expand and factor? Or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base case is incorrect: it should be for $n=1$ (and $a\neq 1$):
$$\sum_{j=1}^1 a^j = a = (a)\frac{1-a^1}{1-a}.$$

Then, assume true for $n>1$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n a^j = (a)\frac{1-a^n}{1-a},$$
For $n+1$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} a^j = \sum_{j=1}^n a^j + a^{n+1},$$
by definition, so plug in the expression for $n$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} a^j = (a)\frac{1-a^n}{1-a} + (a) a^n,$$
and simplify the RHS of this expression to prove the result.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood the question.  You aren't trying to prove it is true for all real $a$; you are trying to prove the statement for all natural $n$.

You set $a > 0$, $a \ne 1$ arbitrarily once *and keep it fixed* and prove that for all $n$

$\sum_{j=1}^n a^j = a\frac{1 - a^{n}}{1-a}$.

Step 1: Show for $n = 1$.

$\sum_{j=1}^1 a^j = a^1 = a = a*1 = a\frac{1-a}{1-a}$.  (This is why $a \ne 1$.)

Step 2: Assume true for $n =k$.

Show it is true for $n = k+1$.

Hint: $\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} a^j = a^{k+1} + \sum{j=1}^{k} a^j = a^{k} + a\frac{1-a^k}{1-a}$.

So you need to prove $a^{k} + a\frac{1-a^k}{1-a} = a\frac{1 - a^{k+1}}{1- a}$.

Can you do that.